# Regarding to the size() in setup() function

Tags: processing

Why I can use size(1920, 1080) in setup()
but If I use

```
setup()
  visualContext = new VisualContext(
    new Area(0, 0, 1920, 1080),
    new Area(158, 150, 1340, 950)
  );
  size(visualContext.getGlobalArea().getWidth(), visualContext.getGlobalArea().getHeight());
```

There will be an error

```
When not using the PDE, size() can only be used inside settings().
Remove the size() method from setup(), and add the following:
public void settings() {
  size(1920, 1080);
}
```

I can not find any doc about this topic.

Curious, can size only be initialized by constant but variable?

Answer (score 4):

use settings if you want to invoke size with parameters.

```
VisualContext visualContext = new VisualContext(
    new Area(0, 0, 1920, 1080),
    new Area(158, 150, 1340, 950)
  );

void settings() {
  size(visualContext.getGlobalArea().getWidth(), visualContext.getGlobalArea().getHeight()); //<>//
}
```

https://processing.org/reference/settings_.html